# how to perform a timed event in linux server using php

Tags: php, mysql, time

Is there a way to perform timed events using php from server such that if for example time is 24:00 delete value in mysql database etc.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, by creating a never ending loop that checks the time, but you REALLY do not want to do this. If you are using linux you should set up a cron job to run a PHP script